# Call PowerShell command with parameters from cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line-interface

I want to call `PowerShell` command from `cmd`. For example, let it be `get-content`.

> [PowerShell.exe Command Line Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)

OK, my case will be

```
powershell -command <string> [<CommandParameters>]
```

In my case it will looks like

```
powershell -command "& {get-content <???>}" <filepath>
```

But it doesn't works. I can't understand how to pass `cmd` arg `<filepath>` into the command string `"& {get-content <???>}"`.

Comment: `powershell -command " #PasteCodeHere "`. So, in your case, it should be `powershell -command  "Get-Content 'c:\temp\textfile.txt' "`. No need to use the `&`, only when running against a file. `powershell -command "& 'C:\Temp\myps.ps1'"`

Comment: But I need to pass filepath as argument from `cmd`. Is there only one way to do it - use external `ps1` file? Looks lame.

Comment: use a BAT/CMD environment variable [OR any other variable that works in the shell] in the argument string. ///// a better solution would be to run things entirely in PoSh ... most utility apps can be called from inside powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @Abraham Zinala  you can write a cmd file `test.cmd` with the following :

```
powershell -command "Get-Content 'c:\tmp\toto.txt' "
```

If you want to write :

```
.\test.cmd c:\tmp\toto.txt
```

You can put into your cmd file :

```
powershell -command "Get-Content '%1' "
```

Comment: So, the answer is "no way". Anycase if I want to run ps-script from cmd I need to create intermediate script file. So sad :(